# Is there a common ancestor for the Slaadi and the Slann?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming, wfrp-1e

Both the Slaadi and Slann originated from White Dwarf / Games Workshop in the UK sometime in the late 70's or early 80's. The writer Charles Stross who contributed the Slaad to White Dwarf's Fiend Factory [claims it came to him in a fever dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slaad#Development_and_licensing).

I know even less about the Slann. I think they first appeared in a Warhammer Battle Suppliment in an encounter called The Magnificent Sven.

My question is basically in the title. Do these two very similar trans-dimensional races of frogmen have a common ancestor? Is there a common ancestor based in actual mythology?

Comment: I've edited your question to not presume the ancestor is necessarily in mythology, since it could equally likely be from a book, or folklore (which isn't mythology), or so on, without any mythological roots whatsoever. I've left present however a question asking whether there _is_ a mythological ancestor, in case that detail is of particular importance to you to have clarified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as far as I can tell. You seem to already have a source for the Slaadi so I shan't cover that.

It seems to be commonly accepted ([1](http://fightingfantasist.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/lust-for-lustria.html), [2](https://forum.rpg.net/archive/index.php/t-428263.html), [3](http://www.goodman-games.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=8159)) that the Slann were originally created due to an in-joke at Games Workshop about Erich von Daniken's Chariot of the Gods which became Chariot of the *Frogs* instead.

Thematically they do seem rather similar to the idea hypothesised in the book.

> It involves the hypothesis that the technologies and religions of many
>   ancient civilizations were given to them by ancient astronauts who
>   were welcomed as gods. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chariots_of_the_Gods%3F)

Weirdly, frog-men don't seem to really show up much in mythology though so it does look like the ideas behind these two races are independent. Indeed, apart from an amphibian appearance, they are very different in background, motive and temperament.

Comment: Thanks for the well researched answer. Slaad pre-date the Slann and many of the writers of Warhammer Fantasy Battle and WFRP were staffers at White Dwarf.